# Linq query return coumn value null handle

Tags: c#, linq, casting

In the datatable return one column list, in this scenario table return null value, I want to handle null values

```
DataTable PreviousQuarter = GroupFive.Tables["PreviousQuarter_108_49_100_51"];
LastQuarter.Merge(PreviousQuarter);

var AHCT = (from ah in PreviousQuarter.AsEnumerable()
            where  ah.Field<int>("ParameterID") == 10 
                || ah.Field<int>("ParameterID") == 11
                || ah.Field<int>("ParameterID") == 12 
                || ah.Field<int>("ParameterID") == 13          
            select ah.Field<int>("Tot_Tkts_Closed")).ToList();

if (AHCT == null)
{
    Response = "";
}
```

It will come null , I am getting error  Specified cast is not valid .
how to handle this error.

Comment: `ToList` will never return `null`; it will either return an instance or throw an exception, so testing `AHCT == null` is pointless. As for the invalid cast, that's happening in one of those `Field<int>()` calls. Try `Field<int?>()`.

Answer (score 1):

Your are selecting a value which is not available in table and before getting the result you type cast it into int.
That's why it throws error.
Its better to select first and then convert it into int.

Answer (score 1):

I think @madreflection gave you the answer in the comments.

Since you're getting this error:

> Specified cast is not valid

my guess is that you have a null value in the `Tot_Tkts_Closed` column. In that case, cast to nullable int `int?` instead.  Update this line:

```
select ah.Field<int?>("Tot_Tkts_Closed")
```

The other possibility is `ParameterID` is null, in which case a similar change should resolve it: `ah.Field<int?>("ParameterID")`.

---

Rather than checking if the list is null you could check to see if its empty. In that case, use the `Count` property:

```
if (AHCT.Count == 0)
{
    Response = "";
}
```